# Why does z-index only work for positioned elements?

Tags: html, css

I know that z-index only works with positioned elements, but I am wondering why this is the case. Is there a good reason for this behaviour or is it just one of those semi-arbitrary specification decisions?

I came across this issue when working with code like this:

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <img class="not-positioned" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
    <img class="positioned" src ="http://placekitten.com/g/400/500">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
img {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.positioned {
    position: relative;
    left: -60px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.not-positioned {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/666nzL6j/

You'll notice that this works according to specification (the `.not-positioned` image is behind the `.positioned` image despite `.not-positioned`'s higher z-index value), but I am having a hard time understanding the rationale for this behaviour.

Comment: Simple google search http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements are positioned in all three dimensions

- on the x-axis using `left` and `right`
- on the y-axis using `top` and `bottom`
- on the z-axis using `z-index`

Of course, `z-index` is not 100% similar to the others, as it only describes a stacking instead of a "real" position, but that's all you can do on the z-axis, since you don't have fixed boundaries on that axis.

So, you need to give an element a `position` value other than `static` if you want to set its `z-index`. If your problem is as simple as in your example, you can also give the other element a negative `z-index`:

```css
.positioned {
    position: relative;
    left: -60px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation as well as an alternate method of setting z-index to -1.

Answer (score 1):

From Mozilla Developer Network - *[position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)*:

> The position CSS property chooses alternative rules for positioning
> elements, designed to be useful for scripted animation effects.

Thus, in order to change an elements position, you need to tell it not to be static and you do that by applying a position property.

Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/Understanding_CSS_z-index

Comment: The last link is broken: *"Page not found"*