# Why does z-index not work on my header to show my shadow?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

My content below my header positions itself above the header which I gave a higher `z-index`.

As a consequence, it hides the shadow on the header.

Even stranger behavior is when I add a negative margin on the content below: You can see the header text but now has a background color from the content.

```css
header {
  z-index: 999999;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0ex 2ex hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div {
  background: red;
  height: 8em;
  /* margin-top: -5em; */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>Some text<br><br>Some more text</header>
    <div>My div</div>
</body>
```

I tried putting a negative `z-index` on my content and that solves the problem, but then all elements in my content become inactive.

(E.g., I can't click or hover anything any more.)

Comment: I did checked that duplicate, but I must have tried two things at a time. Sorry, guys. 
 Unfortunately I cannot delete my question now. It says "you cannot delete .. because others invested time in answering it".  :'(  Just want to lower the fragmentation of stackoverflow.

Comment: The first sentence is nearly incomprehensible (e.g., are one or more words missing?). Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70411855/edit)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with `z-index`, be sure to set positions to the elements. Otherwise it can generate strange behavior.

So here just add `position: relative` to the `header` and it will work well (even in the case you add that negative `margin` to the `div`).

In this particular example, there isn't any need to add `position: relative` to the `div` (in order to solve the issue), but you will not make a mistake doing so. When it comes to playing with z-index, setting positions to the overlapping elements helps the browser to understand the context better.

```css
header {
  z-index: 999999;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0ex 2ex hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 8em;
  margin-top: -5em;
}
```

Here is, BTW, a very good article covering all the z-index issues: *[Four reasons your z-index isn’t working (and how to fix it)](https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/)*

Answer (score -1):

To add to [Biswajit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70411855/why-does-z-index-not-work-on-my-header-to-show-my-shadow/70411902#70411902), here's [a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28465649/8723748) (Stack Overflow answer) on why *position* is needed.

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681). And: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: I think a comment would be more appropriate than a link-only answer. You have enough reputation points to comment.